# depth subscriber roslibpy

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do we get a proper sized (640x480) array from the depth message?

my subscribed depth final array is a (640x480x2).... when it should be (640x480). The rgb topic is fine at (640x480x3). I tried both topics that publish depth data. i suspect that this is a decoding error given that the depth is UC16? this is a quirk of the roslibpy rosbridge library....you have to decode the base64 data that travels through the rosbridge.

code snippet of the depth callback.

```
def subscribe_depth(depth_raw_msg):
  print('depth_raw_msg keys: ', depth_raw_msg.keys())
  print('depth_raw_msg encoding: ', depth_raw_msg['encoding'])
  depth_data_raw = depth_raw_msg['data']
  depth_header = depth_raw_msg['header']
  depth_base64_bytes = depth_raw_msg['data']
  depth_bytes = base64.b64decode(depth_base64_bytes)
  depth_data = np.frombuffer(depth_bytes, dtype=np.uint8)
  depth_data = depth_data.reshape(480, 640)
```

i think its a problem specifically with this line:

```
 depth_data = np.frombuffer(depth_bytes, dtype=np.uint8)
```

driving test code:

```
Topic = roslibpy.Topic(ros, '/wx250s/camera/depth/image_raw', 'sensor_msgs/Image')
print('is connected:', ros.is_connected)
while ros.is_connected:
  test_depth_data = Topic.subscribe(subscribe_depth)
```

error: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 614400 into shape (480,640)`

Thanks for coming to my dumpsterfire :)

**UPDATE:**
We get the right array size when changing the suspect line to `np.frombuffer(depth_bytes, dtype=np.uint16)`, but I don't know if that's right.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403939/depth-subscriber-roslibpy/) by [dwd394](https://answers.ros.org/users/108750/dwd394/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2022-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is common for depth values to be published as type `uint16`.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dwd394](https://answers.ros.org/users/108750/dwd394/) on 2022-07-19**:
Thank You, yep that worked.